# JavaScript equality from Underscore docs

Tags: javascript

I saw this on the underscore.js docs under _.isEqual. Why is this the case?

```
var moe   = {name: 'moe', luckyNumbers: [13, 27, 34]};
var clone = {name: 'moe', luckyNumbers: [13, 27, 34]};
moe == clone;
=> false
```

Is it because strings and numbers aren't objects so they can be compared, but JS doesn't allow you to compare Arrays or Object Literals which are Objects?

Comment: Identity comparison. They're referencing two different objects.

Comment: two different objects are never equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object literal always defines a new object and thus variables `moe` and `clone` refer to different objects.

> An expression comparing Objects is only true if the operands reference the same Object

[read more about comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript#answer-1144249) has a nice asnwer with a deep "look-alike" comparison function

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify property:

```
JSON.stringify(moe) === JSON.stringify(clone)
```

Note: Order of the properties is very important. In this case, properties of `moe` should be in the same order as properties of `clone` or vice-versa.

Comment: That will work assuming it's an exact copy, but will fail if the keys are out of order, such as `clone = {luckyNumbers: [13, 27, 34], name: 'moe'}`. The objects are still effectively the same (order doesn't technically matter), but would fail the JSON test. The only true way to test equality is to recursively iterate over the entire object.

Comment: I agree with you. Thus the only way would be to compare the properties of variables recursively.